# Specify starting point of foreach enumerator in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumeration

I have a rake file that pulls in data from an external CSV file and enumerates through it with:

```
CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
```

What is the most effective way (in ruby) to specify the starting point within the spreadsheet?

:headers => true allows me to start importing from the second line, but what if I want to start a line 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .drop(#rows to ignore):

CSV.open(file, :headers => true).drop(20).each do |row|

Comment: Nice. Is that much faster?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby enumerators  include a [drop method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop) that will skip over the first `n` items.

When not passed a block, `CSV.foreach` returns an enumerator.

You can use

```
CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true).drop(20).each do |row|
```

This will skip the first 20 data rows (the header row does NOT count as one of those twenty).

Comment: the only thing is it still load all file in memory. anyway, good solution.

Comment: Yeah just noticed that. Can't think of a good reason it would return an array instead of another enumerator

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200014/ruby-is-there-something-like-enumerabledrop-that-returns-an-enumerator-instead

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was able to get it to work with CSV.open(file, :headers => true).drop(20).each do |row|.  Please edit your answer to show ".open" instead of ".foreach" and I will select it as correct.  Thx again.

Comment: Oops, I inadvertedly downvoted your answer. Didn't mean to. Can't undo  that until you modify the question! I will be watching for it and fix it.